# Gtk+2.0, How can i remove an attached widget to a GtkTable?

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk, gtk2

this is my first question on Stack Overflow,so I hope you can be friendly if I will make some mistakes.

I'm trying to learn a little bit of Gtk2.0 mechanisms. I'm a newbie with this library so I'm trying to construct a basic GUI.

I created a 230x150 window, attached a GdkPixbuf icon and learned how to trigger signals, in particular I'm interested on showing/hiding the icon on pressing of an arrow key.

I have achieved the objective of showing the icon but I'm not finding the way to hide this one. I looked at the documentation, but anything seems to be working.

I attach the code below so you can help me better. Thanks in advance for hints.

http://pastebin.com/iUJRc6hw

Comment: By the way, if you are just learning GTK then start with GTK 3! GTK 2 is quite obsolete by now, and GTK 3 is soon going to turn into GTK 4...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to hide the icon with `gtk_widget_hide(app->icon)`.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer but it still doesn't work. I used the function that you have suggested but the function has a GtkWidget as a parameter and app->icon is a GtkPixBuf so i used gtk_widget_hide(gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf(app->icon)); but nothing happens when gtk_widget_hide is triggered.

Comment: Well, if you create a new widget with `gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf()` and hide _that_, then it won't hide the existing image. You need to save a pointer to your existing `GtkImage` in your `app` struct and hide that.